# problem-related to structures and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
  int data;
  struct Node* link;
};
struct Node* A;
int main(){
  struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp->data = 2;
  temp->link = NULL;
  A = temp; // in this line i have doubt
  return 0;
}
```

The doubt is that:
A and temp both are pointer to node. *A = temp* can have two meanings:

1. We are copying the address of temp in A, hence A will point to the same address.(means both of them are same identities/variables)
2. We are copying the elements of temp and assigning it to elements of A.(means both of them are separate identities/variables). We generally do this in structures.

So please help me to understand it.

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `temp`. And `temp->data = NULL` should probably be `temp->link = NULL`.

Comment: temp is a pointer, not a struct, so temp->data = 2; is invalid - you're assigning to memory that has not been allocated. You need to either declare "Node temp;" to allocate it on the stack, or allocate an instance with new(). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397288/dynamically-allocate-memory-for-struct

Comment: If you were allocated memory for temp or A, or assign them an address of some variable then they both pointed to same address.

Comment: @Barmar yeah but i am asking something else please check the description. i know the topic isn't clear but i can't put this whole doubt in the topic.

Comment: @Corbell yeah you mean i need to use malloc to assign the memory for it first. yeah that was one of the mistakes i did but i was asking something else plz read the descriptions to get what i am asking. By the way thanks.

Comment: Please don't tag questions as c and c++, they are different languages and will produce different answers

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a pointer just copies the address, not what the pointer points to. So `A = temp;` makes `A` and `temp` point to the same address.

If you want to copy the elements, you have to dereference the pointers: `*A = *temp;`

Comment: The OP's code has enough undefined behaviour that ignoring it is misleading.  Technically, in C++, `*A=*temp` won't copy anything in the above code, because (a) the above program's behaviour is already unspecified, and (b) there is no line where `*A=*temp` doesn't also result in unspecified behaviour.  Wording this correctly is challenging, but unless you do I think this answer is incorrect *and* harmful to the questioner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931123/copying-one-structure-to-another       **Check this out ** in this they have used A=temp for copying the elements.

Comment: @uditkumar11 Because that's a structure variable, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first right. How can you assign Null in`temp->data = NULL;` here data is `int` type.

Your option 1st is correct.

And you have just declared structure pointer variable but not initialized.

Your code had some errors I fixed. Run the code below and see both A and temp have same address after `A=temp;` statement which means both are pointing same thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
   int data;
   struct Node* link;
};  // you had forgot ';' here
struct Node* A;
int main(){
   struct Node *temp;
   temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
   // this allocates memory and assign its address into temp structure pointer
   temp->data = 2;  
   temp->link = NULL; // here you was doing mistake
   A = temp; // in this line i have doubt
   printf(" Address of pointer A %p", A);
   printf("\n Address of pointer temp is %p",temp);

 return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have still any doubt.

Comment: yeah i wrote temp->data instead of temp-> link. really sorry for that

Comment: please check code snippet and ask if any doubt or your answer is still not clear to you

Comment: Thanks my doubt is about to clear. If i declare a new struct like (temp1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  ) now if i do temp1 = temp then what does it mean either i am assigning the address of temp in temp1 or am i copying the elements

Comment: pointer variable is different than normal variables. they are meant to point other variables of same type. That is why you have to allocate memory and then assign it to struct pointer variable here

Comment: Technically a pointer holds the address of the object it points to. But the `printf` text is misleading. A is a pointer and there is an address. The term "Address of pointer A" would be `&A`.

Comment: I mean addresses that pointers are holding they are same. as you have assigned `A=temp`

Comment: You mean if we don't assign memory to that pointer to node (like in case of A=temp) then it will store the address of that temp. But if we assign memory to it then(like in case of temp1=temp) it will copy the elements as memory is already assigned to it.

Comment: no copy of element i never said . you are messing up things.

Comment: so how can i copy the elements of one struct to another.          You can check this link in this they have done it the same way i thought (temp1 = temp) to copy the elements.       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931123/copying-one-structure-to-another

Comment: you should read it bro. Here what I anyone can do is give direct answer to specific query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216914/discussion-between-ankit-mishra-and-uditkumar11).